# Work in incognito mode VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, debugging, incognito-mode

i need debug a project in incognito mode, i set the argument --incognito but this open each letter opens in a normal window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juFr4.png)

Comment: Could you debug it in your side now? If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here. In addition, the latest VS2017 would be 15.7.2 version.

Comment: I had to restore the default settings, this is the solution

Comment: Do you mean that reset your VS/Browser settings? Anyway, glad to know that it works well now. If my solution is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer or you could share yours. Have a nice day. If you got any debugger issue, feel free to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I could debug it in my side.

[image]

You could troubleshoot this issue with the following steps:

(1) Update your VS 2017 to the latest version 15.7.1, and use the default settings.

(2) Please make sure that you set the browser correctly like this document:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-incognito-mode-for-any-broweser-in-visual-studio

(3) Create a default Web Form app, select the Google Chrome-incognito as the default browser, debug it again. You could just run your app with Ctrl+F5 before you really debug it with F5, view the result.

(4) Maybe you could update your browser to the latest version, view the result again.